# Using assembly for sharing enums

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF log viewer application in MVVM style, where the view (UI) is decoupled from the core logic (using view model in the way)

I have an assembly called LogViewer.Core.dll, in this assembly there is an enum LogLevel that has some values.

In the UI, that is in a diffrent assembly (LogViewer.UI.dll) there is a listbox that should contain an items source of LogLevel enums, this list is binded to a list of LogLevel in the view model, at the same assembly (for querying reasons)

I dont want that LogViewer.UI.dll will held a reference to LogViewer.Core.dll

Should I create a LogViewer.Shared.dll that will hold this namespace and other of the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I create a LogViewer.Shared.dll that will hold this namespace and other of the same?

Yes

Comment: I have never endorsed a one word answer before; but there is a first time for everything I guess.

Comment: He basically answered his own question. If I added more words, they would be ". That's a standard pattern for sharing common types."

Comment: Yes; my point was that in this case your one word is quite sufficient.